# RabbitMQ Connection Factory could not find System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions in my app bin

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, assembly-binding-redirect, .net-4.8, assemblybinding

I have the following code

```
var factory = new ConnectionFactory()
{
    HostName = "path.to.host.net",
    UserName = "guest",
    Password = "guest",
    VirtualHost = "myhost"
};
var connection = factory.CreateConnection();
```

The last line of the above complains with the following error

> FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly
> 'System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The
> located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
> reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

I checked the Fusion Log and it says the following

```
Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Path/To/Web/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = C:\Path\To\\Web\bin
Calling assembly : System.Threading.Channels, Version=4.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Path\To\Web\web.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: C:\Users\fahadash\Documents\IISExpress\config\aspnet.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/fahadash/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET Files/vs/699f3d52/97d4d2c/System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/fahadash/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET Files/vs/699f3d52/97d4d2c/System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions/System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Path/To/Web/bin/System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.DLL.
WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: Revision Number
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80131040). Probing terminated.
```

I opened the DLL's found in the `bin` in IL Disassembler and checked the manifests and found the following

System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.DLL is 4.2.0.1
The above is dependent on System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe 4.0.4.1 which is there in the bin already.

So 4.2.0.0 is a mismatch with a 4.2.0.1 so I decided to add the following Binding Redirect

```
<dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.0.1" newVersion="4.2.0.1" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

I still get the same runtime error complainign that it did not find Extensions 4.2.0.0. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

**Duplicate Binding Redirects are ignored by clr.**

This is embarrassing.

I found out that I had two binding redirects for the same `System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions` assembly, and system was using the first one found and ignoring the second one. And there was no complain about duplicates.

Hoping this answer will save someone else's time in future.

Comment: Man, been hours into this. I didn't have duplicates in my config, but trying to find out why System.Threading.Channels calls the .0 version when .1 is what we get in the build directory. Super annoying. Binding redirects are a pain in plugable infrastructures.  This did get me to the next problem though. Thanks!

Comment: @TravisWhidden Can you post an answer including what was different in your case?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I downgrade to version System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions 4.5.3. For some reason microsoft put this dll with a different assembly version than the version in nuget.

Answer (score -2):

Add binding redirect to C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config. It works for me but I dont know how it possible to use it in production...